# How to know most active day of the week and most active time of day your app is used on Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

I understand that Firebase Analytics captures User Engagement data. I can see the most active Activities from my Firebase dashboard.

In the Firebase dashboard, is it possible to know the most active day of the week and most active time of day your app is used?

Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is very much possible.

So go to the `Dashboard` in your `Analytics` Tab in the Firebase Console.

> 1-day, 7-day, and 30-day active users are plotted over time. Summary
>   values at right show the number of active users as of the last day of
>   the date range.

So from the drop-down menu select `This Week` and you can see on which day you have the most number of `Active Users` Daily, Weekly and Monthly. It also shows the drop/increase rate from the previous date.
You can also add your custom filters for the same.

**EDIT**-

In the Analytics Tab go to `StreamView` where you can check the `Users/Events` in the last 30 minutes with the location.This might come handy for you if you check this tab on the day you expect the maximum number of users.

Comment: I downvoted [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46651915/827263) to another question based on a misreading of the question. If you want to undelete your answer, I'll withdraw my downvote. On the other hand, your point is also covered in the other answers.

Comment: The reason for deleting the answer was that yes  the point is already mentioned in other answers. So if there is an edit in the question maybe I'll update my answer.

Comment: @NovoLucas Not sure what this thread is about but your answer resolved my question. Thank you!

Comment: @NovoLucas However, one is not able to see the most active time of the day. The analytics data is limited to day granularity.

Comment: You know the Overflow community is pretty strict when it comes to the quality of the answer! It was just that.

Comment: Yes we can't as of now see time but I believe you can get something if you create a custom filter for custom hour, as it is in the Google Analytics. Also you have an option to connect your project with BigQuery and I think that also provides lots of insights. So you should play around with that too ;)